# Помогите решить задачу по информатике

Tags: c++, математика

**Условие:**

Совсем скоро у Пети день рождению и он в нетерпении ждет этого праздника. Его друзья слонята решили сделать ему подарок и приготовить идеальный торт.

По мнению слонят идеальный торт должен состоять из ровно N ярусов, каждый из которых представляет собой цилиндр. Однако, при определении идеальности высота цилиндров не важны, важны лишь их радиусы, поэтому яруса можно считать кругами. Яруса кладут друг на друга от самого большого до самого маленького так, чтобы они имели общий центр. Так как все ярусы одинаково красивы и важны, то ни одним нельзя пренебрегать, торт считается идеальным только тогда, когда видимые площади всех N ярусов ровны, если смотреть на торт сверху.

Слонята решили, что радиус наибольшего яруса их торта должен быть R. Помогите слоненкам вычислить каким же будет радиус малого.

Выведите единственное число радиус наименьшего яруса с абсолютной погрешностью, не превышает 10^-4.

**Пример:**  Вход. данные:
        N(количество ярусов) = 4
        R(радиус) = 7
    Вывод:
            3.5

Видимая площадь каждого из четырех ярусов будет равной PI * 3,5^2

Comment: В чем состояла ваша попытка решения? В чем конкретно затруднение?

Comment: "Яруса" - это что такое? Неужто множественное число от слова "ярус"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у вас есть N кругов, то

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дальше все очевидно? (Хотя и сама эта формула выводится в полпинка...)

Comment: Как-то с выводом формулы ты все усложнил

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Почему? Площадь N-го круга - N площадей первого круга, нет?

Comment: Равна. Но как-то это не очевидно. Имхо, мое доказательство нагляднее

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Площадь второго = первого+первого. Третьего = второго + первого. Четвертого... - по-моему, проще уж некуда... На каждом шаге добавляется площадь первого круга...

Answer (score 0):

1. Суммарная видимая площадь будет равна площади нижнего круга
2. Делим ее на N и получаем видимую площадь каждого яруса
3. Верхний ярус виден полностью
4. По площади круга находим его радиус